# How to select all variables in a data.frame that are listed in a text file (in R)?

Tags: r, dataframe, read.table

My programming problem is that I have a list of strings, which are variable names, in an Ascii format file, such as `variables.txt`, e.g.

```
A
B
C
D
```

From a `data.frame` in `R` those variables matching the names in `variables.txt` should be selected. For example:

```
var = c("A", "B", "C", "D")
(dat=data.frame(A=1,B=2,C=3,D=4,E=5,F=6))
  A B C D E F
1 1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Followed by

```
dat[,var]
  A B C D
1 1 2 3 4
```

So the problem maybe comes down to reading `variables.txt` into `var`. If I give:

```
var <- read.table("variables.txt")
```

The result is again a `data.frame` which cannot be used for sub-setting. What is the most efficient way to complete this task?

**Edit:** I found out that

```
var <- as.vector(as.matrix(read.table("variables.txt")))
```

does the trick. But perhaps there are more efficient ways.

Comment: Try `readLines("variables.txt")`.

Comment: You can try with `?scan`

Comment: In my example, `var` is a vector which can be used for sub-setting. In the ascii file the variable names are listed row-wise, so they form one column (which potentially may be big in the sense that there are many rows).

Comment: @WeihuangWong `readLines` does the trick

Comment: @bouncyball if I do that I get error `Error in .subset(x, j) : invalid subscript type 'list'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this way, with var here entered as a data.frame  : you need to be explicit on vector reference to use it for subsetting :

```
dat<-data.frame(A=1,B=2,C=3,D=4,E=5,F=6)

var<-data.frame(variable=c("A", "B", "C", "D"))
dat[,names(dat) %in% var$variable]
A B C D
1 2 3 4
```

Subsetting with a logical vector works fine. 
If you need to specify an order, try with 'match':

```
var$variable<-rev(var$variable)
dat[,match(var$variable, names(dat))]

D C B A
4 3 2 1
```